# Equality of two linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, examples-counterexamples

Two Linear transformations $L$ and $K$ are equal if and only if they have same kernel and same images.

I have no idea how to prove or give a counter example.

Can someone give me a hint to the right way!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true. Take $L,K\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $L(x)=x$ and $K(x)=2x$. They are different but they have the same kernels and the same images.

Comment: If i take x =1 then i get $L(1) = 1$ and $K(1) = 2$, how are they same? i think i'm missing something but don't know what :( sorry for extra question

Comment: What I wrote was the both functions $K$ and $L$ have the same image; it is $\mathbb R$ in both cases. If, for each $x$, $L(x)=K(x)$ then *of course* that the functions are equal (without assuming anyting about their kernels). That's what two functions being equal *means*.