# Images of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Today I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2567761/equality-of-two-linear-transformations/2567764?noredirect=1#comment5299522_2567764) about Images and kernel however the answer was correct but now it created some confusion about images and i read from many sources what i understood is:

If $L$ is a linear map $L:R_v \rightarrow R_w$ then images of $L$ are elements from $R_w$ where $L(v) = w \in R_w$ (in this case $w$ is an image of $v$).

I asked in that question:

Two transformations $L$ and $K$ are equal if and only if they have same kernel and same images.

I got answer that $L(x) = x$ and $K(x) = 2x$ have same images but they are different.

$L$ maps $x$ to $x$ and $K$ maps $x$ to $2x$ so my question is how are these two images same because ($x,2x \in R_w)$ so images are $x$ and $2x$ but they are not same? It could a stupid question but it created lots of confusion  can some clear this concept for me? Thanks.

Comment: The images are equal *as sets*. Here is one particularly excruciating argument:

From a set theoretic point of view: if $ x \in \mathrm{Im} \,L$, then $2x \in \mathrm{Im}\, L$, since the image is a subspace. However, this also means that $2x \in \mathrm{Im}\, K$, since there is clearly some element $a \in \mathbb R$ so that $K(a)=2a=2x$, namely, $a=x$. But then, by the subspace property, we also have that $\frac{1}{2} \cdot2x \in \mathrm{Im} \, K$, since it is a subspace, which means that $x \in \mathrm{Im} \, K$.

Comment: think of linear transformation as a linear function. will two functions be same if they have same range? What you asked meant something like will two functions be same if they have same zero set and range.

Comment: @AndresMejia So two images are same if they span same subspace/vector-space and should not necessarily be same $vectors$ but vector-space/subspaces?

Answer (score 3):

Let us fix a well known vector space: $\mathbb R$. Let $L, K\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ defined as $Lx = x$, $Kx = 2x$.

Then we have $$\ker L = \{ x\in\mathbb R\mid Lx = 0\} = \{ x\in\mathbb R\mid x = 0\} = \{0\},\\ \ker K = \{ x\in\mathbb R\mid Kx = 0\} = \{ x\in\mathbb R\mid 2x = 0\} =\{0\},$$

and $$ \operatorname{im} L = \{ y\in\mathbb R\mid (\exists x\in\mathbb R)\ Lx = y\} = \{ y\in\mathbb R\mid (\exists x\in\mathbb R)\ x = y\} = \mathbb R,\\ \operatorname{im} K = \{ y\in\mathbb R\mid (\exists x\in\mathbb R)\ Lx = y\} = \{ y\in\mathbb R\mid (\exists x\in\mathbb R)\ 2x = y\} =\mathbb R.$$

Of course, this actually works for any vector space*, not just $\mathbb R$.

$^*$ *Except if the ground field is of characteristic $2$.*